# Limit of a sequence bounded by numbers less than one

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ two sequences of positives numbers such that

$a_{n+1}\leq q_{n}a_{n}+ b_{n}$

for each integer $n\geq 1$. Assume that

(1) $0<q_{n}<1$ for each $n\geq 1$

(2) $\lim_{n}b_{n}=0$

Can we infer then that $\lim_{n}a_{n}=0$? I know that if $q_{n}:=q$, for each $n$ and some $0<q<1$, then the assert is true.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think $b_n=1/n$ and something like $q_n=(1-1/n!)$ should provide a counterexample.

Comment: @JackyChong Sure, but it is only required that $q_n < 1$ for each $n$, without restriction on the limit.

Comment: @arkeet It says $0<q<1$.

Comment: @JackyChong, it's $0\lt q_n\lt 1$, not $0\lt q\lt 1$.

Comment: @arkeet I misread.

Comment: Indeed if $\limsup q_n < 1$ then $\lim a_n = 0$, so any counterexample must have $\limsup q_n = 1$.

Comment: @arkeet Agree, I have added a comment in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: If $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} q_n <1$, then your claim is true. Otherwise, you have the above counterexample in the comments.

Here's a hint for the proof when $\limsup q_n <1$.

**Hint:** For sufficiently large $n$, say $n>N$, you have
\begin{align}
a_{n+1} \leq (q+\epsilon)a_n + \epsilon
\end{align}
where $q+\epsilon<1$, which means
\begin{align}
a_{N+k} \leq&\ (q+\epsilon)a_{n+k-1}+\epsilon \leq\  (q+\epsilon)^2a_{n+k-2}+(q+\epsilon)\epsilon +\epsilon\\
\leq& \ldots \leq (q+\epsilon)^ka_N+ (q+\epsilon)^{k-1}\epsilon+(q+\epsilon)^{k-2}\epsilon+\ldots +(q+\epsilon)\epsilon +\epsilon\\
\leq&\ (q+\epsilon)^ka_N + \frac{\epsilon}{1-(q+\epsilon)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$a_{n+1}=b_n+q_na_n=b_n+q_nb_{n-1}+q_nq_{n-1}a_{n-1}=\cdots\\=b_n+q_nb_{n-1}+q_nq_{n-1}b_{n-2}+\cdots+(q_nq_{n-1}\cdots q_2)b_1+(q_nq_{n-1}\cdots q_2q_1)a_1$$

Since $0\lt q_n\lt1$ for all $q_n$, we have

$$a_{n+1}\ge(q_nq_{n-1}\cdots q_2)(b_n+b_{n-1}+\cdots+b_1)$$

By letting $b_n={1\over n}$, any sequence $q_n$ for which the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty q_n$ converges (i.e., $\sum \ln q_n$ converges) will give $a_n\to\infty$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer